# How to move imageview in B4A

Tags: vb4android

How to move ImageView (added in the designer) in B4A, I google it but I can't find how to move it. imageview1.left = 100 does not works (I use main for scripting)

Comment: Try imageview.left = 100dip

Comment: i found it i need to use b4xview=MyControl